# O que usar no lugar de .getIntent

Tags: android

Alguém sabe o que qual sintaxe que uso no lugar de .getIntent. Segue meu código:

```
 Intent myIntent = Intent.getIntent();
    if(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(myIntent.getAction())){
        String query = myIntent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        Toast.makeText(this, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Quando coloco Intent.getIntent() ele não compila pois este método já está deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá, Artur.

Não é bem assim que se faz. Pelo o que vejo no seu código, você está querendo usar uma intent recebida de um pesquisa extrair dela o texto digitado na busca. A questão é que você não está pegando a instância do intent recebida pela pesquisa fazendo Intent.getIntent(URI), esse método não serve para isso. Seu myIntent não contém a query.

Por padrão, quando um usuário executa uma pesquisa no aplicativo, uma nova instância da sua activity é criada e executada. Você poderá pegar essa intent chamando o método `getIntent()` em um dos métodos do ciclo de vida da Activity, como por exemplo, dentro do método `onCreate()`.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_funcionariostatus);

    Intent myIntent = getIntent();
}
```

Você pode fazer uma interceptação da intent de busca antes de uma nova instância da sua Activity ser criada e executada (Não indico essa interceptação, pois abrir uma instância para cada busca que o usuário realizar é interessante para se manter um histórico e dar a possibilidade dele voltar a busca anterior apenas voltando nas telas anteriores). Isso pode acontecer no método da Activity `startActivity(Intent intent)` que é chamado toda vez que você faz `startActivity(intent)`, que por sinal é feito automaticamente quando o usuário executa a busca. A intent recebida nesse método é a mesma que você capturaria no `onCreate()` fazendo `getIntent()`, pois é ela é transferida a activity que será instanciada. Sendo assim, você pode fazer a verificação para confirmar ser a intent de busca e, logo em seguida, fazer o que deseja. Você vai impedir que uma nova activity seja aberta ao evitar que o método do pai seja chamado `super.startActivity(intent);`, pois é ele que iniciará o processo de instanciação da nova activity. Dessa forma:

```
@Override
    public void startActivity(Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            //Do something with the query...
        } else {
            super.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Indico a leitura desse artigo: http://www.materialdoc.com/search-filter/

Comment: Tássio, você deve ser ano-luz mais experiente do que eu, pois não entendi quase nada do que você falou. Mas obrigado mesmo assim pela ajuda. Entrei no link que você passou. Ali consegui entender melhor. Vou tentar aqui, se conseguir deixo um comentário aqui depois. Obrigado novamente.